# How to remove constant parts of a string in R

Tags: r, string, parsing

I would like to remove constant (shared) parts of a string automatically and retain the variable parts.
e.g. i have a column with the following:

```
D20181116_Basel-Take1_digital
D20181116_Basel-Take2_digital
D20181116_Basel-Take3_digital
D20181116_Basel-Take4_digital
D20181116_Basel-Take5_digital
D20181116_Basel-Take5a_digital
```

how can i get automatically to for any similar column (here removing: "D20181116_Basel-Take" and "_digital"). But the code should be find the constant part itself and remove them.

```
1
2
3
4
5
5a
```

I hope this is clear. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a regex: it will remove everything before 'Take' and after the underscore character:

```
vec<- c("D20181116_Basel-Take1_digital", 
"D20181116_Basel-Take2_digital",
"D20181116_Basel-Take3_digital",
"D20181116_Basel-Take4_digital",
"D20181116_Basel-Take5_digital",
"D20181116_Basel-Take5a_digital")

sub(".*?Take(.*?)_.*", "\\1", vec)
[1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "5a"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I would like to do it automatically, meaning, the code should determine "^D20181116_Basel-Take" and ""_digital$""  itself, based on the column.

Comment: Could you provide a possible name for similar columns please?

Comment: i mean a column in the format: x1y, x2y, x3y, ..., i want to get rid of the "x" and "y"s of the string, the  "x" and "y"s sould be automatically detected. they are constant in all cells of the column.

Answer (score 0):

with gsub():

assuming you have a dataframe df and want to change column

```
df$column <- gsub("^D20181116_Basel-Take","",df$column)
df$column <- gsub("_digital$","",df$column)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I would like to do it automatically, meaning, the code should determine "^D20181116_Basel-Take" and ""_digital$""  itself, based on the column.